# ¿Cómo obtener todos los nombres del json en python?

Tags: python

Estoy intentando obtener todos los nombres de la api

```
https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=ninja&searchLanguage=es
```

pero no consigo cómo recorrer para tener todos los nombres
[image]

Aquí dejo mi pequeño código:

```
import requests


url = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=ninja&searchLanguage=es")


variantes = url.json()


for i in variantes["data"]:
    print(i["variants"][0]['options'][0]['name'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estuviste muy cerca la estructura pero era diferente:

```
import requests


url = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=ninja&searchLanguage=es")


variantes = url.json()


variantes2= variantes["data"][0]["variants"][0]["options"]

for i in variantes2:
   print(i["name"])
```